# Can't resolve 'fs', Truffle Box for Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, node-modules, ganache

I am working on an Ethereum decentralized app by following this guide:
https://github.com/Quintor/angular-truffle-box

This requires:

```
truffle
@angular/cli
ganache-cli
```

I have tried some tricks like `npm update fs`, setting fs to false in the browser like this:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
```

Yet none of these seem to work and I keep getting errors in `./node_modules/node-dir/lib/paths.js` `readfilesstream.js` and `readfiles.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `truffle unbox Quintor/angular-truffle-box` I just cloned the master branch `angular-truffle-box-master`.

From there on I opened a terminal and follow along with the tutorial, except for step 2, `truffle unbox Quintor/angular-truffle-box`.